# Adding Tooltip to Bootstrap Progress Bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a tooltip to Bootstrap's [progress bar](http://alademann.github.io/sass-bootstrap/components/#progress). However, I need for it to be a CSS-only tooltip.

I was using [hint](http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/), but it seems that it does not work; I'm guessing that there is a conflict somewhere.

This was the tooltip css, which works on divs and all that, bot not on `progress-bar`s

```
/**
 * def tooltip
 */
.hint--def:before {
    border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;}
.hint--def:before {
    margin-top: -12px; }
.hint--def:after {
    margin-left: -18px; }
.hint--def:before, .hint--def:after {
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    color:#6c6c6c;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%; }
.hint--def:hover:after, .hint--def:hover:before, .hint--def:focus:after, .hint--def:focus:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px); }

/**
 * Info
 */
.def:after {
    color:black;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0 0px 0px #193b4d;
}
.def.hint--bottom:before {
    border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF; }
```

Comment: Can you please share the link where you are trying?

Comment: @SazzadHossainKhan I'm working on a development server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a simple CSS tooltip to any HTML element as long as the tooltip HTML is within the target.

So for example:

```
<span class="tooltip-target">
    Hover over me
    <span class="tooltip-content">I am the tooltip!</span>
</span>

.tooltip-target { position: relative; }

.tooltip-content { 
     display: none; 
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: -10px; // set this whatever you want
}

.tooltip-target:hover .tooltip-content {
    display: block;
}
```

You could get fancy and use opacity with CSS3 transitions instead of toggling the display for a smoother effect.

Comment: Seems nice and it works, but it only appears on the progress bar (It gets cut off and the tooltip only appears as far as the progress bar, even when I set overflow:visible;). Am I missing something?

Comment: Make jsFiddle if you want some more help.

Comment: I have the some issue that it's getting cut. Here is a bootply: http://www.bootply.com/4GhxR4d1Aw